# Multiplos uploads PHP e inserir no banco mysql varias imagens

Tags: php, mysql

Talvez seja duplicado, mas não consegui encontrar nenhuma explicação que segue no meu raciocínio.

Tenho o seguinte código retirado da Web, através de uma vídeo aula.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="administrativo/processa/adm_proc_cad_produtos.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagens</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="arquivo[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
                </div>
    </div>

</form> 


<?php       

        if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
        // informações da imagens
        $imagem = $_FILES['arquivo'];   
        $numArquivo = count(array_filter($imagem['name']));
        // Local de upload
        $pasta = "../../../imagens/produtos/";
        // Permissões de arquivos
        $tipo       = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
        $maxsize    = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
        // mensagens
        $msg        = array();
        $errorMsg   = array(
                                1 => 'Arquivos no upload é maior qye o limite definido de upload_max_filesize, por favor reduza suas imagens',
                                2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE',
                                3 => 'Upload feito parcialmente, e pode conter erros',
                                4 => 'Upload de arquivo não realizado'
                            );

        if($numArquivo <= 0)
                echo 'Selecione uma imagem';
            else{
                for($i = 0; $i < $numArquivo; $i++){
                    $name = $imagem['name'][$i];
                    $type = $imagem['type'][$i];
                    $size = $imagem['size'][$i];
                    $error = $imagem['error'][$i];
                    $tmp = $imagem['tmp_name'][$i];

                    $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                    $nomeUnico = rand().".$extensao";

                    if($error != 0)
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                    else if(!in_array($type, $tipo))
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro tipo imagem não permitida!";
                    else if($size > $maxsize)
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Tamanho do(s) arquivo(s) maior que o limite 10MB!";
                    else {
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta."/".$nomeUnico))
                            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload realizado com sucesso!";
                        else
                            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro! Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente!";
                        }
                }
                    $nomeimagem = implode(',', $nomeUnico);
                    $result_produtos = "INSERT INTO produtos (nome, situacao_produto_id, categorias_id, imagem, valor, texto, created) VALUES ('{$nome}', '{$situacao_produto_id}', '{$categorias_id}', '{$nomeimagem}', '{$valor}', '{$texto}', NOW())";
                    $resultado_produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produtos);                        
 // fecha else
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Para realizar o upload o arquivo e gravar no banco MySQL.

O código realiza o upload de 1 vários arquivos, e faz o rand() no nome, e envia a pasta, o problema é gravar no banco.

Gostaria que na minha tabela (imagem) com as colunas ID | imagem | data

na minha (coluna imagem) ao fazer o upload de várias imagens elas fossem inseridas na seguinte forma 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg - na coluna imagem realiza-se o upload do nome da imagem em uma unica coluna.

Tentei realizar o

```
$nomeimagem = implode(',', $nomeUnico);
```

Antes de inserir no banco mas o parametro implode não funciona.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: as demais informações estão sendo salvar corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é que a função `implode()` precisa de um `array()` e você estava passando uma `string`, tente assim:

```
$extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
$nomes[]=$nomeUnico = rand().".$extensao";
```

Depois do loop `for()`, coloque assim:

```
$nomeimagem = implode(',', $nomes);
```

> [Referência da função **implode()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)

Comment: perfeito, resolvido... era isso que estava me perdendo. Funcionou...
Agora o próximo problema, como exibir os itens desta coluna separados, apontando somente o caminho deles, utilizando método `explode()` ?

Comment: Que otimo, fico feliz em poder ajudar.
Sim, para listar vc usa o `explode()` para separar os nomes que foram unidos pela ","

Comment: Ok... muito obrigado... ajudou muito

Comment: Eu quem agradeço